# reasons of SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document

Tags: php, xml, soapfault

I have tried to find where is the problem over three days. Does any one knows the main reason of this error

```
SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document
Stack trace:
[10:00:31] (10049) #0 /var/www/user/wsapi/Folder/FolderService-wip.class.php(26): SoapClient->__call('getFolderList', Array)
```

Comment: *does any one knows the main reason of this error* That you have no XML document. What does the server return?

Comment: i can open the wsdl file in my browser how to check the server?

Comment: I don't think the WSDL file is the problem. You don't expect a WSDL back when you call `getFolderList`. I think the problem is that the server doesn't return an XML document when `getFolderList` is called.  You can trace the request and response by running something like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) in the same context as PHP.

Comment: i tag _getLastResponse() and _getLastRequest() but no trace I will try with Fiddler

Comment: There is no fiddler mac version

Comment: There are alternatives http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: thnx it looks like there is no request and _getLastRequest()->NULL  _getLastResponse()->NULL